# Get Open Graph Data by Facebook API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I want to get some data (title, description, image) using url to page and 'Facebook SDK for .NET' library.

I don't receive image when I use GET request:
[image]

Request implementation:

```
        var facebookClient = new FacebookClient(GetAccessToken());
        try
        {
            dynamic data = facebookClient.Get(url);
            return new OpenGraphData
            {
                Id = data.og_object.id,
                Title = data.og_object.title,
                Description = data.og_object.description
            };

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {                
        }
```

Is it possible to create POST request using this library?

[image]

If not please tell me another way to get this data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request data manually

```
        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
               var json =
                    client.UploadString(String.Format(
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/?id={0}&access_token={1}", url, at), "POST");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
```